# Convert case statement to logical operator in the where clause

Tags: sql

Can you please help me convert this piece of code to logical operator and use `'like'` not `'='` cause i know it's not efficient to put case statement on the where clause. Tia! Here's the code.

```
Where
(@reftype = '0' or
  (@refnum = case @reftype when 'BN' then refBN when 'C' then refC when 'O' then refO else 'n/a' end)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for editing Tim. I did translate it but my superior says its wrong. Here is my code: where (@reftype = '0' or (@reftype = 'BN' and refBN like @refnum) or (@reftype='C'  and refC like @refnum) or (@reftype='O' and refO like @refnum) or (@reftype='n/a')) i dont know what im missing.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
or @refnum = case @reftype when 'BN' then refBN when 'C' then refC when 'O' then refO else 'n/a' end)
```

with

```
or (@reftype = 'BN' AND @refnum = refBN) 
or (@reftype = 'C' AND @refnum = refC) 
or (@reftype = 'O' AND @refnum = refO) 
or @refnum = 'n/a'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate it to boolean logic in this way:

```
WHERE  @reftype = '0 'OR @refnum = 'n/a' 
OR (@reftype = 'BN' AND @refnum = refbn)
OR (@reftype = 'C'  AND @refnum = refc)
OR (@reftype = 'O'  AND @refnum = refo)
```

But note that `CASE` in the `WHERE`-clause is not inefficient per se.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Looks like the one I translated too. I don't know why my superior is not happy about it.